# SoundEffect raised an error while assigning buffer from SpeechLib

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

I am developing Windows Phone 7 application which read some text and speak the text.

The micsoroft library - *interop.speechlib.dll* converts my text into buffer(byte array). And ***SoundEffect*** plugin of Windows Phone 7 speaks it.

This all working fine, but sometimes it creates problems by raising bellow error-

**Buffer is invalid. Ensure that the buffer length is non-zero and meets the block alignment requirement for the audio format**

Code to speak is as per below:

```
SoundEffect se = new SoundEffect(buffer, 15000, AudioChannels.Stereo);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
se.Play();
```

Please suggest me, where I am doing wrong.

**Edit**
From some test I conclude that the root cause of issue is generation of buffer. Below is code to generate buffer from text.

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {

     SpeechLib.SpVoice oVoice = new SpeechLib.SpVoice();
     SpeechLib.SpFileStream cpFileStream = new SpeechLib.SpFileStream();
     cpFileStream.Open(filename, SpeechLib.SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite, false);
     oVoice.AudioOutputStream = cpFileStream;
     oVoice.Speak(value, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
     oVoice = null;
     cpFileStream.Close();
     cpFileStream = null;

     byte[] ImageData=File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
     return ImageData;
 }
```

Thanks,
Naresh Goradara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some test it works by setting channel mode.
It works by setting channel mode to mono.

```
SoundEffect se = new SoundEffect(buffer, 30000, AudioChannels.Mono);
```

View the difference between these at [mono vs stereo](http://www.mcsquared.com/mono-stereo.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you did not honor the block alignment requirements. Quote

> **What exactly is block alignment and
>   how do I calculate it?**
>
> In a single sentence, block alignment
>   value is the number of bytes in an
>   atomic unit (aka block) of audio for a
>   particular format. For PCM formats the
>   formula is extremely simple: “Block
>   Alignment = Bytes per Sample * Number
>   of Channels”. For example, block
>   alignment value for mono 16-bit PCM
>   format is 2 and for stereo 16-bit PCM
>   format it’s 4. We have a couple handy
>   helpers that can help calculate the
>   block aligned values –
>   GetSampleSizeInBytes and
>   GetSampleDuration convert from time
>   units to block aligned byte value and
>   back.

Source http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashtat/archive/2010/06/03/soundeffect-creation-in-xna-game-studio-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I found the root cause for this. Its not at SoundEffect but at buffer generation. I have added my code, please have a look and suggest.